# Does keypress events not apply to Backbone.js Views

Tags: events, backbone.js, keypress

I don't understand if anything is wrong in this idea but the Backbone Views just don't trigger keypress, keyup events. I have created a simple shopping list app is JsBin for you to inspect. In the chrome inspector the `ul` of the view shows the keyup event but it does not occur when i hit some keys in the keyboard. I need the idea to navigate Treeview using the keyboard events

#### Jsbin

http://jsbin.com/arucom/2/edit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033010/how-to-capture-the-key-event-from-a-view

Comment: @rkw Hi thanks for the duplicate. So this isn't possible with what i got now ? If i had links instead will it be possible ?

Comment: the focus would need to be on the links.  the easiest way is to [hook onto the document](http://jsbin.com/arucom/3/edit) like the suggestion mentioned, but you would have to remember to unbind the event when the view is removed.

Comment: @rkw I don't get it. How come `document` when it does not have any input elements can get to trigger these events but my `view` does not.There must be some way to do this, let me try it out and post an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the question @rkw linked You might want to have a look at this SO question [Why audio events are not firing with BackboneJS but others are?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461954/why-audio-events-are-not-firing-with-backbonejs-but-others-are)

Basically backbone.js uses delegation to bind events, which only works with delegate-able events.

You can bind to the keypress manually in the initializer

```
 initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this);
          $(document).bind('keyup', this.navigate);
    },
```

Comment: I did this in another way. But since this is the only answer i will mark it answered +1

Comment: I had a similar problem with Mousetrap.js. Adding `_.bindAll(this);` solved the problem.