# backbone.js bind to audio events

Tags: backbone.js, html5-audio, backbone-events

How to do it?
I searched Stack Overflow, find one similar result, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        //some variables
    },
    //creating audio element
    setAudio: function(ogglink, mp3link){
        //code, that works
    }
});     
var Playlist = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: Player
});
var MyPlaylist = new Playlist([ 
    //some songs here
]);    
var OneSongView = Backbone.View.extend({     
    //added some 'template' and 'el' code
    initialize: function () {
        this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);   
    },
    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.model.setAudio(this.model.get("ogglink"), this.model.get("mp3link"));
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        //declaration of some events
    },
    //event functions
});    
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    //router code
});    
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

If I add in events something like `timeupdate`: `somefunc`, it'll not work, if I add code like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461954/why-audio-events-are-not-firing-with-backbonejs-but-others-are), I'll have errors :(

Comment: oh, can't remember cuz of totally rebuilding, just don't work or 'this.$("audio")' is not a function.. something like that

Comment: Ah ha! That is because, unlike the example solution you linked to, you aren't setting `this.$el`'s HTML until your `render` method fires. You won't be able to attach the event handlers on `this.$("audio")` until you do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Backbone.View` event handlers are delegated to the view's `el`. This means that any events that fire inside the view must bubble/propagate up to its `el` before your handlers will catch them.

Unfortunately for you, HTML5 audio and video elements do not propagate their events up through the DOM the way most other elements do. The only way to handle these events is to add eventListeners directly to the `<audio>` element after it has been inserted into the DOM.